# How much water can exist as a gas in a closed container?

Tags: pressure, water, equilibrium, kinetic-theory

If i leave water in a closed container at some ambient temperature what proportion of that water will turn into a gas at equilibrium?

Maybe it is easier to solving this by first answering what is the ratio between steam and water vapour at a certain pressure and temperature? I'm not making much progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an equilibrium is reached between a liquid phase and the corresponding gaseous phase (where there is only the vapor of the liquid), it appears that the pressure of the gas only depends on the temperature (and not on the quantity of liquid left, as long as there is still some liquid). This value of the pressure is called *vapor pressure*.

Now, let's imagine that there is some liquid $A_l$ in a container which already contains some gas $B$, then it appears that the *partial pressure* of the gaseous phase $A_g$ equals the vapor pressure $P_{vap,A}$. Let's call $n_{A,g}$ the quantity of gas $A$, $V$ the available volume of the container (that is, the initial volume of the container minus the volume of $A_l$) and $T$ the temperature, then since $P_A = P_{vap,A}$, ideal gas law gives

$$P_{vap,A}V = n_{A,g}RT$$

or $$n_{A,g} = \frac{P_{vap,A}V}{RT}$$

So it appears that the amount of vapor in the container depends on the available volume and on the temperature, but not on the amount of liquid introduced (as long as there is still some liquid inside).

At $20°C$, $P_{vap,water} = 23.4$ mbar, so this gives a concentration $c = 0.71$ mol/m$^3$, or $c_m = 13$ g/m$^3$